# Pycaret classification.compare_models does not display results grid

Tags: python, pycaret

From the documentation and tutorials for pycaret, I expect the classification.compare_models() function to return a grid such as...

|  | Model | Accuracy | AUC | Recall | Prec. | F1 | Kappa | MCC | TT (Sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Naive Bayes | 0.9567 | 0.0000 | 0.9556 | 0.9619 | 0.9561 | 0.9348 | 0.9378 | 0.0076 |
| 1 | K Neighbors Classifier | 0.9467 | 0.0000 | 0.9444 | 0.9633 | 0.9430 | 0.9197 | 0.9295 | 0.0077 |
| 2 | Extreme Gradient Boosting | 0.9467 | 0.0000 | 0.9444 | 0.9633 | 0.9430 | 0.9197 | 0.9295 | 0.0521 |
|  | etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My code

```
from pycaret.classification import *
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
setup_result = setup(data=df, target='Class')
best = compare_models()
print(best)
```

I get lot's of output like this...

```
Initiated  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .              11:35:34
Status     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Loading Dependencies
Estimator  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     Compiling Library
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Model, Accuracy, AUC, Recall, Prec., F1, Kappa, MCC, TT (Sec)]
Index: []                                                     
                                                                 
Initiated  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .           11:35:34
Status     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Loading Estimator
Estimator  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Compiling Library
                                                                 
                                                                 
Initiated  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .           11:35:34
Status     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Loading Estimator
Estimator  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Compiling Library
```

And this at the end...

```
Initiated                         11:35:34  
Status              Compiling Final Models  
Estimator  Light Gradient Boosting Machine  

<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x000002562E9A6B20>
LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt', class_weight=None, colsample_bytree=1.0,
               device='gpu', importance_type='split', learning_rate=0.1,
               max_depth=-1, min_child_samples=20, min_child_weight=0.001,
               min_split_gain=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=31,
               objective=None, random_state=123, reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0,
               silent='warn', subsample=1.0, subsample_for_bin=200000,
               subsample_freq=0)
```

But I never get the grid I'm hoping for.
I'm running Python 3.8 with Anaconda in Git Bash on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further research I found that IPython support is required for the grid to print - it will not print in console text,

I got the output I was looking for by running the code in a jupyter notebook session.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to do this right after the `best = compare_models()`

```py
best = compare_models()

# Get you the results in a pandas dataframe (results object)
results = pull()

# Print out the results
print(results)
```